# What is the philosophy behind Redux completely replacing the state instead of mutating it each time?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I heard that it's better to do testing this way but I don't understand why. What purpose does it serve to build a new state each time something changes rather than mutating what is already there? Is it faster?

Answer (score 1):

No it's not faster. Mutating the state directly is usually faster.

Returning a new state makes reducers easier to test and predictable (because there is no side effect), also 
 we can prevent some unexpected behaviors from happening. For example If you are using `PureComponent` and you mutate state directly, you component may not update as you expected, because `PureComponent` use `===` to compare props.

Consider the code below, we are trying to render a list:

```
// current state
const list = ['foo', 'bar']

// we mutate the state directly
list[1] = 'hihi'

// in shouldComponentUpdate of a PureComponent
props.list === nextProps.list // true
```

In this case the component will not be aware of the update.

In addition to `PureComponent`, there are some optimizations in react-redux rely on this convention.

Comment: With you example, if you don't mutate list directly but use a new list, how does the new list get to nextProps and the old list stay with props?

Comment: Why not? Redux just passes the new list to the component

Comment: Actually what react does is very simple. newProps will just be assigned to the instance `inst.props = nextProps`

Comment: And of course it calls the lifecycle methods before, for example: `inst.shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext)`

Answer (score 0):

Take a read of the [Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html#state-is-read-only) on the issue, but basically it makes each update much more preditable, which makes everything from testing to rendering simpler.